# Need Assistance counting even and odd integers

Tags: java

Ok so I am reviewing for an exam in Java, and one of the problems asks us:
We wish to develop a program that will count the number of even and odd integers in a set ("even" meaning divisible by 2, "odd" meaning not divisible by 2). We will use zero as an indicator that the set has been completely entered, and this zero should not be counted as part of the set. Ask the user for a sequence of integers, terminated by zero. Output the number even integers and the number of odd integers.

When I run my code, for some reason the first variable is ALWAYS counted as even, regardless what the integer is.  I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Example: I type 23, 22, 25.  It says 2 even 1 odd.  However, if I type it 22, 23, 25 it says 1 even 2 odd.

Here is my Code:

```
public class Problem4_Exam1Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
        int x = IO.readInt();
        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;

        while(x != 0) {

            x = IO.readInt();

            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                even = even + 1 ;
            }else{
                odd = odd + 1 ;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(even + " even " + odd + " odd ");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Perfectly valid question, and a good one to boot. Upvoted.

Comment: What is `IO.readInt()`?

Comment: Don't set x outside your loop: for (x = IO.readInt(); x != 0; x = IO.readInt()) { ... }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you always ignore the first number and count the terminating `0` as *even* which gives an impression that first number is always counted as *even*.

You can fix this by reordering your `while` loop as

```
while(x != 0) {
    // check odd-even first
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        even = even + 1 ;
    }else{
        odd = odd + 1 ;
    }
    // then read next int
    x = IO.readInt();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the first input inside the while. It's better if you use a do while for this.

```
System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
// x = IO.readInt();  => remove this line
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
while ((x = IO.readInt()) != 0) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        even = even + 1 ;
    }else{
        odd = odd + 1 ;
    }
}
```

EDIT: code edited to fix what @jschultz410 point out.

Answer (score 1):

The first number entered is never evaluated:

```
int x = IO.readInt();
```

Then when the loop is entered it is overridden before evaluated:

```
while(x != 0) {     
        x = IO.readInt();
        ...
}
```

One solution is to move the reading to the end of the loop:

```
while(x != 0) {
        ...     
        x = IO.readInt();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here. First, your very first value is being consumed, but it is not being used in your while loop. Also, you count your last value, which is 0. Reading the value last helps to solve that problem.

```
public class Problem4_Exam1Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
        int x = IO.readInt();
        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;

         while (x != 0) {

            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                even = even + 1 ;
            }else{
                odd = odd + 1 ;
            }

            x = IO.readInt();

        }

        System.out.println(even + " even " + odd + " odd ");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might stem from the fact that the first number seems to be being skipped. You are putting it into x and then overwriting it immediately without looking at it. Try using a do-while loop instead, and putting the `x = IO.readInt()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help!  As for scanners we use an IO module provided to us, so we can't use scanners "YET".

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    while(true) {
        String s1 = bufferRead.readLine();
        int x = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        if(x==0)    
            break;
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            even = even + 1 ;
        }else{
            odd = odd + 1 ;
        }

    }
            System.out.println(even + " even " + odd + " odd ");

        }
```